# Sentence with "lui rester"?

Tags: pronoms

My questions are about the bolded sentence below<sup>1</sup>. (The earlier sentences are there to give context) :

> Assise sur le coin du lit, dans la lumière de la lune filtrant entre
> les persiennes, son regard ahuri planté dans le mien, Denise tenait
> ses cheveux dans ses mains. Loin de sa tête. **Ne lui restaient que
> quelques touffes de poils éparses sur le crâne.**

DeepL's translation:

> Sitting on the corner of the bed, in the moonlight filtering through
> the blinds, her bewildered gaze planted in mine, Denise held her hair
> in her hands. Far from her head. **Only a few tufts of hair remained
> scattered on her head.**

Questions:

1. a) Would the bolded sentence be correct, and mean the exact same thing, if I inserted an impersonal "Ils" at the beginning: "**Ils** ne lui restaient que ..."? (The reason I want to do this, is because the original sentence seems to not have a subject). b) Is there a connotation or stylistic difference made by not having a subject?
2. What the "lui" is for? Would the bolded sentence make sense if it was deleted? (My confused guess: Is "lui" used with "rester" here because a body part ("le crâne") was mentioned?)

---

<sup>1. From "La Bête à sa Mère", by David Goudreault, chapter 1</sup>

Comment: This is a great example of how bad that site is, especially for literary translation. That is a misuse of the verb scatter in English and a mistranslation of: quelques touffes de poils éparses sur le crâne. Which is: a few tufts of hair remained here and there on her scalp.

Comment: @Lambie: It's not a misuse of the verb *scatter*; it's a misplacement of the adjective *scattered*. *Only a few scattered tufts of hair remained on her scalp* would be fine.

Comment: @PeterShor I'd say that's inaccurate. Generally speaking, I don't think of scattered describing things that are attached, like tufts of hair to a scalp. The Oxford says: "occurring or found at intervals or various locations rather than all together". What it doesn't say is that the semantic trait of scattered includes "not attached" in many instances. Unless the tufts of hair had been ripped out of scalp. That's why I used here and there and specifically avoided scattered. (I know that for graphs et alia the points are described with that word).

Comment: I specifically avoided scatter for that reason, Tufts of hair, ripped from the victim's scalp, lay scattered around on the floor.

Comment: @Lambie: So [scattered tufts of grass](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scattered+tufts+of+grass&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscattered%20tufts%20of%20grass%3B%2Cc0) are tufts of grass that have been uprooted and thrown haphazardly around the landscape? I really don't think so. There's a subtle semantic difference between the verb *scatter* and the adjective *scattered*.

Comment: I believe I said in most instances, not every instance. If you want to use scattered tufts to mean spread unevenly over the scalp, be my guest.

Comment: “There aren’t many compounds that can push hair follicles into their growth cycle so quickly. Some topical agents induce **tufts of hair here and there** after a few weeks, but very few compounds have this potent an effect so quickly,” he said. https://www.shortlist.com/news/science-might-have-just-found-a-cure-for-baldness From a scientist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence would be correct and mean the exact same thing with a subject, but that subject would then be the singular impersonal *il*:

> **Il** ne lui **restait** que quelques touffes de poils éparses sur le crâne.

In the original sentence, the actual subject is ***Que quelques touffes de poils***, as the plural ***restaient*** shows:

> *Seules quelques touffes de poils éparses lui restaient sur le crane*.

**Lui** represents Denise. Without this pronoun, the sentence would have been slightly odd:

> *Ne restaient que quelques touffes de poils sur le crane.*

It is not incorrect but it somewhat gives the impression that the hairs had the choice to leave but a few of them decided to stay.

Note also that the author, to reinforce the image and the surprise it inspires, deliberately uses the wrong word for hair, *poils*, while *cheveux* would be expected on a scalp.

Comment: 1) can you articulate what nuance or stylistic difference is created, between the original sentence vs having the impersonal subject "Il"? 2) It confuses me that "Que" is a word in the subject, without "ne". Textbooks etc make it seem that when "que" means "only", it always has a "ne" with it. So, if I wanted to undo the inversion and write the subject first, could I write: "Ne que quelques touffes do poils éparses lui restaient sur le crâne"? 3) Would the original sentence make sense if I deleted "lui"?

Comment: 1) The sentence is more literary than with the impersonal subject. It wouldn't be used in speech. 2) You are right, this *que* works with a *ne*. It is present in the original sentence. Moving the subject before the verb forces to replace it by something else, like *Seules* in my rephrasing. *Ne que quelques* doesn't work at all. 3) Answered in the meantime.